# SVN repo access control for multi repositories

Tags: macos, apache, svn

Can't seem to get restricted access to my multi repositories. it seems to be an all or nothing configuration. I have one location with 8 or more different repos. Example: http://mydomain.com/svn/repos/repo1 and /repo2 ect...

seems all can read every repo? not sure why?

most of my setup was from this configuration example on Mountain Lion:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3874020

All repos are under the same dir. Apache server on Mac, https.conf has correct modules set, I'm using a separate server name.conf file for the main SVN access control:

server.conf file looks like:

```
<Directory "/Users/iMac/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

LoadModule dav_svn_module     libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   libexec/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn/repos
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd/passwords
    SVNPathAuthz on
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/passwd/htauthz
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /websvn>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd/passwords
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My access file looks like:

```
[groups]
all = tom, dick, harry\

[/]
# * = r

[helloworld:/]
@all = r
tom = rw

[repo1:/]
tom = rw
harry = r
dick = r

[repo2]
dick = rw

[repo3]
harry  = rw

[xcode]
tom = rw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `Satisfy Any`
2. Use in htauthz

   `[/]`

   `* =`

Comment: I had the `* = r` but i'm trying to restrict r and rw to specific users. Apache requires authentication from the client and to do this they use `Staisfy Any` and `Require valid-user`

Comment: I get 403 Forbidden if I remove `*=r` and every `valid user` can read if I leave it in.  I want select `valid users` to be restricted from reading and writing to repos!

Comment: @BarclayVision - **re-read** ["Authorization Options"](Authorization Options) chapter from SVN Book! You **must** remove `Satisfy` for non-anon-access, 403 for `* = ` is next question. Period

Comment: I did remove the 'Satisfy' and changed `* = r` to `* = ` and still 403 Forbidden ... again with `* = r` I have to authenticate but all valid users have read access?

Comment: sorry for the long chain of questions - Your original answer is correct, my issue was the browser caching my user credentials and trying to login with cached user... I still can't figure out how to access via browser with different user, but all other svn is working fine...